# Jssor - Can I use your slider for commercial use?

Tags: jssor

Please provide some details about - commercial use of "Jssor"(www.jssor.com) slider.

Thanks,
Dev

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about licensing details and not programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah for sure. Jssor Slider is definitely free!